# How to get oil stain off stone mastic asphalt (SMA)?

Tags: asphalt

Does anyone know how I can remove, or even lessen, a dried-in oil stain from stone mastic asphalt?  I already used washing up liquid on it and it did improve it, but I would like to try and remove it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use laundry detergent powder and wood ash, add water to make a thick paste (like toothpaste), scrub it into the stain with a stiff broom or scrubbing brush, cover with plastic and let it sit for a few days then wash it off.